# How do you query a Mongo db for rows containing a column with a specific type?

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

I have a collection that has ended up with a column containing an updated timestamp, sometimes as a text field, sometimes as a date field. I am looking for the syntax to execute a query to find all rows that contain that field as a date type.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$type`  with `$not`

Checking the `not` scenario. If type is not of string, then consider that doc.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EppfwvKvGsM)

```
db.collection.find({
  "key": {
    $not: {
      $type: "string"
    }
  }
})
```